# Ensure data integrity in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-design

I have to make some changes in a small system that stores data in one table as following:

```
TransId  TermId  StartDate   EndDate     IsActiveTerm 
-------  ------  ----------  ----------  ------------
1        1       2007-01-01  2007-12-31  0
1        2       2008-01-01  2008-12-31  0
1        3       2009-01-01  2009-12-31  1
1        4       2010-01-01  2010-12-31  0
2        1       2008-08-05  2009-08-04  0
2        2       2009-08-05  2010-08-04  1
3        1       2009-07-31  2010-07-30  1
3        2       2010-07-31  2011-07-30  0
```

where the rules are:

- StartDate must be the previous
  term EndDate + 1 day (**terms cannot overlapping**)
- there are many terms per each transaction
- term length is from 1 to n days (I
  made 1 year to make it simpler in this example)

**NOTE:** IsActiveTerm is a computed column which depends on CurentDate so is not deterministic

I need to ensure terms not overlapping. In other words I want to enforce this condition even when inserting/updating a multiple rows.

What I am thinking of is to add an "INSTEAD OF" triggers (for both Insert and Update) but this requires to use cursors as I need to cope with multiple rows.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: @Greg, Microsoft SQL Server supports triggers either after or instead of an insert, update, or delete operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got working solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TransTerms_EnsureCon ON TransTerms
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
BEGIN   
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM TransTerms pT
                    INNER JOIN TransTerms nT
                        ON pT.TransId= nT.OfferLettingId
                        AND nT.TransTermId = pT.TransTermId + 1
                WHERE nT.StartDate != DATEADD(d, 1, pT.EndDate)
                    AND pT.EndDate > pT.StartDate
                    AND nT.EndDate > nT.StartDate
                )
    )

    RAISERROR('Transaction violates sequenced CONSTRAINT', 1, 2)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

P.S. Many thanks wallenborn!

Comment: be a good SO citizen then and accept his answer if you found your solution in the link he gave you.

Answer (score 3):

You can find pretty much everything about temporal databases in: Richard T. Snodgrass, "Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL", Morgan-Kaufman (2000), which i believe is out of print but can be downloaded via the link on his [publication list](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html)

Comment: @wallenborn, Why should I read this? It might be very interesting but I have a common problem. Forget about "StartDate", "EndDate" and "IsActiveTerm" column. What I want to achieve is to enforce business rules which force constrain over multiple rows. This can be anything (e.g. prevents from inserting more than five people in the same age).

Comment: Because the trigger you are looking for is on page 135.

Comment: @wallenborn +1 from me. Your answer was a little bit confusing when you said "there is pretty much everything about temporal databases". My example was too specific I guess but it isn't temporal database I have. I was thinking of how to enforce a constrain over multiple rows in general. Eventually it was me being stupid and haven't check out the book you suggested ;) Anyway, thanks for the very specific link. I am going to read this book as it seems to be quite interesting. Cheers!